# What is the language of the following code

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code returned by Laravel:

```
    O:29:"App\Jobs\ConvertOriginalVideo":6:{
      s:36:"\x00App\Jobs\ConvertOriginalVideo\x00input";
s:77:"/var/www/vhosts/lala.com/storage.lala.com/original/series/16727.mp4";
      s:37:"\x00App\Jobs\ConvertOriginalVideo\x00output";
s:78:"/var/www/vhosts/lala.com/storage.lala.com/converted/series/16727.mp4";
      s:6:"\x00*\x00job";
      N;
      s:10:"connection";
      N;
      s:5:"queue";
      s:5:"video";
      s:5:"delay";
      N;
}
```

Laravel `Queue::after` job payload returns this data, how can I extract data from this?

Comment: This isn't code, it looks like json, but it would be helpfull to see the code that creates this output

Comment: Just found out, it's PHP serialize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP serialize produces this code.